# How do I define two different versions of a string for different product flavors?

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I'm building an app which has two flavors - free and paid. These are defined in build.gradle (app) like this:

```
flavorDimensions "mode"
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "appid.free"
        versionName "2.0.4-free"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "false"
    }
    paid {
        applicationId "appid.paid"
        versionName "2.0.4-paid"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "true"
    }
}
```

When I build the different versions, I want certain strings to be pulled in differently depending on which flavor we're building.

So, I have the usual strings.xml file which contains the strings which are common to both flavors.

Then I've defined 2 other versions of strings.xml, in:

```
src/free/res/values/strings.xml
src/paid/res/values/strings.xml
```

These contain the flavour-dependant strings.  Each string has the same name in both files, so that the layout just references the common name and then the correct version should be pulled in.

This works fine when I build the free version, but when I then try to build the paid version I get the following error:

```
Found item String/help_settings more than one time
```

The string "help_settings" is defined in both the free and paid versions of strings.xml, but not in the main version of it. My understanding from reading the online Android Studio documentation is that the build should know which versions of the strings.xml file to use, and should ignore the one it doesn't need, but it seems to be aware of all 3 versions and is therefore finding duplicate definitions.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT TO ADD: When I go to the Activity where the offending string is used, if I highlight it and do "CTRL-B" to go to the declaration, it lists 2 places where it's been declared.  Both those declarations point to the same file: src/paid/res/values/strings.xml

I've checked that I haven't declared it twice in the same file or something daft like that, but I definitely haven't.

Comment: Are you building from within Android Studio or from the command line? If it is from Studio, if you clean the project (Build > Clean Project from the main menu), does that change the results? It sounds like you have things set up properly.

Comment: No, still getting the same error. I cleaned the project and that was fine, but when I then go to "Make Project" or "Run" I get the same error as before.

Comment: Update - tried again a couple of times and it worked! Thanks for the help!